# Compare two JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

Here is my code in PHP,

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT items FROM `ppmp` ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1";
  if($result2 = $con->query($query)) {
   $row = $result2->fetch_array();
  $items2 = $row['items'];
 }
 $items = $_POST['ris4'];
 $items = json_decode($items,true);
 $items2 = json_decode($items2,true);

for($i = 0; $i < sizeOf($items["items"]);$i++){
for($i2 = 0; $i2 < sizeOf($items2["items"]); $i2++){
    $val = $items["items"][$i]["Desc"];
    $val2 = $items2["items"][$i2]["Desc"];
    print_r($val);
    print_r($val2);
    if(strcmp($val, $val2) == 0){
     echo "same";
    }
}
}
?>
```

I am going to substract the Quantity of the products.. 
But i can't detect if the two descriptions is the same..

I use `strcmp()` but it is not working.. i echoed descriptions and it's have same descriptions. but `==` operator is not working.

This is the layout of the `$items2` JSON,

```
{"items":[{"Desc":" Pencil ","Qty":25},{"Desc":" Ballpen ","Qty":5},{"Desc":" Tech Pen ","Qty":20}]}
```

And here is the `$items`,

```
{"items":[{"Desc":" Tech Pen ","Qty":15},{"Desc":" Ballpen ","Qty":4}]}
```

Comment: Recursion probably.  But seeing your two JSON arrays would seriously help..

Comment: Where is this '$result' coming from?

Comment: @Franco.. $result is a count of the first json. $result = count($items->items);

Comment: @Daryl, i must echo the string "same".. in the json, it have same description :)

Comment: It'd still be nice to see both ends of the data. Both php and JSON will help. We do not fully know the layout of your current JSON array

Comment: Why i see `Warning: Array to string conversion` while executing `\array_diff()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `array_diff`. This way you can make sure they match exactly the content in the `JSON` structure.

```
    $it_1 = json_decode($items, TRUE);
    $it_2 = json_decode($items2, TRUE);
    $result_array = array_diff($it_1,$it_2);


    if(empty($result_array[0])){     
        echo "they are same";
    }
```

Comment: if i used json_decode($items.TRUE); i cant use count($items->items);

Comment: @Fawzan  This is also true, but I don't understand why he say that  strcmp($val, $val2) don't work. I have test it on my local host and it works perfectly. Anyway I find your solution a good one. cheers :)

Comment: Well there are lot of approaches, You can either go back from array to stdClass or simply convert the `JSON` to stdClass after the comparison.

Comment: @Franco yep, It would work. but It might cause a problem if the key value pairs are switched. And thanks for the +1.

Comment: @John if you set `assoc` parameter be `TRUE`, you can't access as object like `$items->items`, it's converted into associative arrays. see php manual.

Comment: @check, i tried array_deiff() and there is an error. array to string conversion error. So i tried other way. try to see my edited code.

Comment: it still not working. i print_r and echo, they have the same string. why it is not same?

Answer (score 9):

Suppose we have...

JSON OBJ 1 {"key1": "message", "key2": "message", "key3": "message"}

JSON OBJ 2 {"key2": "message2", "key3": "message3", "key1": "message1"}

Using a code like this one:

```
$responseMatch = json_decode($obj1) == json_decode($obj2);
return $responseMatch ? 'responses match!' : 'responses dont match!';
```

will give you what you want, i've tested in many use cases

Comment: This solution will give the wrong result if the PHP objects are different types, ex: comparing array to stdClass

Comment: @Typewar can you show an example of two JSONs that would cause this to give the wrong result?

Comment: @CharonME the following two JSONs do not show as equal, but arguably should: {"a":[1,2]} != {"a":[2,1]}

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your 'Desc' is a plain text string you can check these in thi way:

```
if (strcmp($val, $val2) !== 0) {
   //they are not the same
}
```

UPDATE:

```
$items1 = json_decode('{"items":[{"Desc":" Tech Pen ","Qty":15},{"Desc":" Ballpen ","Qty":4}]}');
$items2 = json_decode('{"items":[{"Desc":" Pencil ","Qty":25},{"Desc":" Ballpen ","Qty":5},{"Desc":" Tech Pen ","Qty":20}]}');

for($i=0;$i<count($items1->items);$i++){
    for($j=0;$j<count($items2->items);$j++){
        $val = $items1->items[$i]->Desc;
        $val2 = $items2->items[$j]->Desc;
        if( strcmp($val, $val2) == 0 ){
            echo "Item ".$val." match with ".$val2." ";
            //$items2->items[$j]->Qty -= $items1->items[$i]->Qty;
        }else{
            echo "Item ".$val." don't match with ".$val2." ";
        }
    }
}
```

You say that this is not working but I am testing this on my localhost and is working ok.

Comment: It is still not working, try to chekc my updated json in the last.

Comment: Yes I did. You have as decription: Pencil and Tech Pen. If you want to check if they are the same you need to do if (strcmp($val, $va2)  == 0) {

Comment: Can you tell me the value you get from echo $val; and 
    echo $val2;

Comment: Tech Pen Pencil not the same | Tech Pen Ballpen not the same | Tech Pen Tech Pen not the same | Ballpen Pencil not the same | Ballpen Ballpen not the same | Ballpen Tech Pen not the same |

Comment: Whit the comparision function is nothing wrong, this is a 'PHP' function used to compare two strings. But is also necessary that you get the right values here:$val = $items->items[$i]->Desc;
    $val2 = $items2->items[$i2]->Desc;
Which I don't know.

Comment: I see also that your two arrays are of a different length so I don't know if the indexes at a certain point will work correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$items1 = json_decode('{"items":[{"Desc":" Tech Pen ","Qty":15},{"Desc":" Ballpen ","Qty":4}]}');
$items2 = json_decode('{"items":[{"Desc":" Pencil ","Qty":25},{"Desc":" Ballpen ","Qty":5},{"Desc":" Tech Pen ","Qty":20}]}');

for($i=0;$i<count($items1->items);$i++){
    for($j=0;$j<count($items2->items);$j++){
        $val = $items1->items[$i]->Desc;
        $val2 = $items2->items[$j]->Desc;
        if($val == $val2){
            $items2->items[$j]->Qty -= $items1->items[$i]->Qty;
        }
    }
}
print_r($items2);
```

Will output

```
[items] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Desc] =>  Pencil 
                    [Qty] => 25
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Desc] =>  Ballpen 
                    [Qty] => 1
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Desc] =>  Tech Pen 
                    [Qty] => 5
                )

        )
```

Comment: it is working if i set $items1 like that. i tried to prin_r the $items and $items1, they are both the same..

Comment: the difference is, $items = $_POST['something']; do it have effect?

Comment: your answer works but the $items1 must be come from $_POST['something'];

Comment: if `$_POST['something']` is same JSON format or array, you can loop as the same way..